# NumberFormatException after using String.split

Tags: java

I keep on getting a NumberFormatException in my code, but I can't seem to figure out why.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SongCollection
{
    ArrayList<Song> songs;
    public SongCollection(ArrayList<Song> songs) {
        this.songs = songs;
    }    

    public void addSong(String line) {
        String[] parts = line.split("\t");
        int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        int rank = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        String artist = parts[2];
        String title = parts[3];
        Song addedSong = new Song(year, rank, artist, title);
        songs.add(addedSong);
    }

    public void printSongs(PrintStream output) {
        for (int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
            Song song = songs.get(i);
            output.println(song.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The string I used for the addSong method was from [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NewportCS/agazillionsongs-LakeJee/master/aGazillionSongs.txt?token=AJUWNIA-ehEY45s7wSpwmKKpikJ6NG3_ks5Y4JjMwA%3D%3D) input file:

The error I get is "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string "1965" (in java.lang.NumberFormatException)"

EDIT (adding debugger window picture):
[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `parseInt` is picky, make sure there are no spaces in the String, so try `parts[0].trim()`.

Comment: It still gives me the same error :\

Comment: Does the string look right in the debugger?

Comment: Can you confirm what the char array in "1965" looks like (and that there's nothing dodgy there)?

Comment: Yeah, I added a picture to the post so you can see that the String is "1965".

Comment: Yes, but it's important I think to check the underlying char array.  It's possible that there might be a funny character in that string somewhere.

Comment: @RamanSahasi I tried adding another backslash, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @JoeC I'm pretty new to comp sci, so forgive me for asking but what do you mean by the underlying char array?

Comment: Try using `line.split("\\s+");`

Comment: The same error message occurs

Answer (score -1):

```
your input "1965" doesn't contain "\t". so the value of line will be 1965, 
 int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]); 
parts[0] will have 1965 value, and it will be complied successfully, but
 int rank = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
```

part[1] will not have any thing so the NumberFormatException will occur, make sure your input should contain '\t' character and numbers so that the values of parts[0] and parts[1] should be numbers.

Comment: The error occurs on the int year line, so doesn't that mean that the NumberFormatException is occurring on that line too?

Answer (score -1):

I see why I kept on getting an error. I needed to remove the BOM from the file since I was using Notepad to open it. Everything works now, thanks for all the help!